# sqlcmd on Windows/SQL Server 2016: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2016, windows-10-desktop

We recently migrated to Windows 10 in a Windows 2016/SQL Server 2016 environment. The linked servers were supposedly set up the same as on the old network, but the following sqlcmd no longer works:

```
sqlcmd -S DBServer1 -q"Insert into DBServer2.Customers.dbo.Table2 (Field2) Select Field1 From Vendors.dbo.Table1"
```

Fails with:

> Msg 18456, Level 14, State1, Server Database1, Line 1 Login failed for
>   user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Servers and clients are in the same domain. If the code is run from a (non-database) server, it works normally.

Also, if I open up SSMS on a Windows 10 client machine and run the query, the above sqlcmd will afterward execute normally in a command pane, until the machine is rebooted or some amount of time has passed.

Setting up SA logins on the SQL Servers isn't an option. What needs to be configured so that sqlcmd hitting a linked server will work using Windows authentication in the domain?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score -1):

For SQLCMD you'd want to use either the `-E` for windows authentication or `-UYourLogin -PYourPassword`